# XAMPP SSL Error 404

Tags: apache, ssl

I installed SSL certificate on XAMPP server and when I change **DocumentRoot** in **httpd-ssl.conf** to my project's folder It works, yes, but when I'm typing http://localhost it redirects me to https://localhost/xampp and I've got error.

So I won't changing DocumentRoot, just make SSL working on actual Root.
I tried to change **httpd-vhost** file but it doesn

Answer (score 0):

It is funny, I swear I did it.

Into httpd-vhost file I copied something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Now everything is fine.